# Cannot deploy contact to ropsten via remix

Tags: solidity, remix, openzeppelin

I'm trying to deploy a token contract and a crowdsale contract via Remix on Ropsten. However I am running into trouble. Below are both of my smart contracts and an explanation of what is happening.

**MyCoin.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import 'github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/CappedToken.sol';

contract MyCoin is CappedToken {
    string public name = "MY COIN";
    string public symbol = "MYC";
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    uint256 public cap = 500000000000000000000000;

    function MyCoin ()
        CappedToken(cap)
        public
        payable
    {

    }
}
```

**MyCoinCrowdsale.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

import 'browser/MyCoin.sol';
import 'github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/emission/MintedCrowdsale.sol';

contract MyCoinCrowdsale is MintedCrowdsale {
    function MyCoinCrowdsale
        (
            uint256 _rate,
            address _wallet,
            CappedToken _token
        )
        public
        Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token) {

        }
}
```

First I deploy **MyCoin.sol** via Remix and everything runs smoothly as shown in this [txn](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xd5c6cac265a314231055369c45caf013fc4aebb90d0049f4f874a35213c69146).

However, when I deploy **MyCoinCrowdsale.sol** via Remix I get a [txn](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xff6f1368d85cc2b6b3e27d6bcf37da016cf8e319fa9e1ae05b1b550d49aa9f98) error, which states :

`Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am completed stumped.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand why it fails at deployement, and for that, you have to inspect the constructor(s).

`MintedCrowdsale` doesn't have a specific constructor and it inherits of `Crowdsale`, which has [one](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol).

```
  constructor(uint256 _rate, address _wallet, ERC20 _token) public {
    require(_rate > 0);
    require(_wallet != address(0));
    require(_token != address(0));

    rate = _rate;
    wallet = _wallet;
    token = _token;
}
```

You can see the 3 `require` and it's highly probable that you are passing a wrong value for at least one of these parameters.

Comment: Yep, figured out that I didn't provide any params to the my crowdsale about 25 secs after I posted my question.